# Openvpn default repo Ubuntu 18.04 install - database location

Tags: openvpn

From the [doc](https://openvpn.net/vpn-server-resources/configuration-database-management-and-backups/)

> The default is that all configuration is stored in SQLite3 database files.

But I cannot find openvpn sqlite database. The mentioned document lists the paths to the db files. This is one `/usr/local/openvpn_as/etc/db/userprop.db`

I've tried to search only the filename `find / |grep userprop` nothing is returned.

I was using `angristan` openvpn easy install script. Anyone familiar if that script does not sets sqlite as a database but stores all in files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You linked the docs of [OpenVPN Access Server](https://openvpn.net/vpn-server/) but installed [OpenVPN Server Open Source edition](https://openvpn.net/community/), of which the documentation can be found [here](https://openvpn.net/community-resources/).